# Performing calculations on an Integer array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying add on dimension of an array together into a variable using a for loop. I have then using alert to show a pop up box with a value in it just to make sure it is working however the popup box says undefined instead of the value i was expecting. Any ideas?

```
var actor = new Array [
            [20,30,10,30,10],
            [10,20,40,30,0],
            [10,10,20,40,20]]

var n1 = 0;
for (var i  = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
n1 = n1 + actor[0][i];
}
```

Comment: Which dimension do you want to access? Why is `i` going to `6`? Which numbers do you want to add in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating the array correctly, and your `for` loop is going out of bounds.

Here's what it should look like.

```
var actor = [
    [20,30,10,30,10],
    [10,20,40,30,0],
    [10,10,20,40,20]
]

var n1 = 0;
for (var i  = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    n1 = n1 + actor[0][i];
}
```

P.S. You can change `n1 = n1 + actor[0][i];` to `n1 += actor[0][i];`.
You might also consider changing `for (var i  = 0; i < 5; i++)` to `for (var i  = 0; i < actor[0].length; i++)`

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. MY life would be so much easier if i could supply a csv file to Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Remember array indicies are 0-based.  The array `actor[0]` has 5 elements (`0`-`4`), but you're iterating over 6 (`0`-`5`).

When you try to add `actor[0][5]`—which is `undefined`—to `n1`, it becomes `NaN`, because you can't add `undefined` to a Number.

Instead of hard-coding the array length, use its `length` property:

```
for (var i  = 0; i < actor[0].length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

`i < 6` should be `i < 5`.  Also your Array constructor is incorrect.

Try:

```
var actor = [[20,30,10,30,10],
             [10,20,40,30,0],
             [10,10,20,40,20]];

var n1 = 0;

for (var i  = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  n1 += actor[0][i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, It was bit of a noob mistake! Maybe i need some sleep.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `Array` constructor, you use parentheses:

```
var actor = new Array( ... );
```

You can also use the literal array syntax for the outer array, just as you do with the inner arrays:

```
var actor = [ ... ];
```

You are looping outside the array. As the array has five items, you should loop from 0 to 4:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

When you are using this form of loop, i.e. starting from 0 and using the `<` operator, you can see the number that you are comparing with as the length of the loop. As you have 5 items, you do the comparison `i < 5`.

You can also use the length of the array in the loop criteria:

```
for (var i = 0; i < actor[0].length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have a `3 x 5` matrix, if you want to call it this, so you are exceeding the dimension count.

Try being dynamic and replace `6` with the value you are *really* looking for:

```
var actor = new Array [
            [20,30,10,30,10],
            [10,20,40,30,0],
            [10,10,20,40,20]]

var n1 = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < actor[0].length; i++)
{
  n1 += actor[0][i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle to do what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/LuQCD/

It abstracts your sum logic into a function so you can pass in any row of the 2d array you want to get the sum of that row.